# MVC 5 return posted view to same tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application using bootstrap tabs.  It's easy to load the tabs using jQuery method `('tab'.load('url'))`, but when I do a submit action on a razor view, it returns to a full page view.  How can I get the posted data to return to the tab holding the form that posted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a submit, then the whole page will be re-rendered once your action ends - with a return View("viewName").

What you could do (and what you probably want) is to do an AJAX POST instead of submit. This way you still would get your controller action called...